# Compare each row from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, firebird

I have 2 tables. Tables are having same colums and I need to compare them. Simple Join query cannot resolve my problem 'cause table2 can contain many rows appropriate to table 1, but I need to choose the best appropriate row. For example :

### Table 1

duration; price; number; 
1; 3; 5;

### Table 2

duration; price; number; 
1; 3.1; 5;  
1; 3.01; 5;

I need to compare row1 from table1 to row1 and row2 from table 2 and choose the best appropriate(e.g row2 is the best appropriate) and mark the row2 as compared and do not to  compare it next time. I'm using FIREBIRD database and ADODB php library. I wrote some code but it works very long time when I have many records in tables. How can I optimize my code to do this task more faster? 
CODE:

```
$this->connect->BeginTrans();
        $sourceResult = $this->connect->Execute( "SELECT SC_PHONE_NUMBER, SC_CALL_START, SC_DURATION, SC_RATE, SC_ID  FROM ". $this->sourceTableName . " WHERE sc_comparing_id = " . $this->insertedId );

        if ( $sourceResult ) {

            while ( !$sourceResult->EOF ) {
                $result = array();

                $comparationResult = $this->connect->Execute(
                    "SELECT CC_PHONE_NUMBER, CC_CALL_START, CC_DURATION, CC_RATE, CC_ID  FROM " . $this->comparableTableName . " WHERE cc_comparing_id = " . $this->insertedId
                    .   " AND cc_is_compared  = 0"
                    .   " AND cc_phone_number = " . $sourceResult->fields['SC_PHONE_NUMBER']
                    .   " AND " .  $sourceResult->fields['SC_CALL_START'] . " BETWEEN cc_call_start - " . TIME_RANGE . " AND " . " cc_call_start + " . TIME_RANGE
                );


                if ( $comparationResult ) {

                    while ( !$comparationResult->EOF ) {

                        $callStartRating = TIME_RANGE / ( TIME_RANGE + abs( $sourceResult->fields['SC_CALL_START'] - $comparationResult->fields['CC_CALL_START'] ) );
                        $durationRating = 0;
                        $rateRating = 0;

                        if ( $sourceResult->fields['SC_DURATION'] > $comparationResult->fields['CC_DURATION'] ) {
                            $durationRating = $comparationResult->fields['CC_DURATION'] / $sourceResult->fields['SC_DURATION'];
                        } else {
                            $durationRating = $sourceResult->fields['SC_DURATION'] / $comparationResult->fields['CC_DURATION'];
                        }

                        if ( $sourceResult->fields['SC_RATE'] > $comparationResult->fields['CC_RATE'] ) {
                            $rateRating = $comparationResult->fields['CC_RATE'] / $sourceResult->fields['SC_RATE'];
                        } else {
                            $rateRating = $sourceResult->fields['SC_RATE'] / $comparationResult->fields['CC_RATE'];
                        }

                        $totalRating = $rateRating + $durationRating + $callStartRating;
                        $result[]  =  array(
                            'sc_id' =>  $sourceResult->fields['SC_ID'],
                            'cc_id' =>  $comparationResult->fields['CC_ID'],
                            'rating' => $totalRating
                        );
                        $comparationResult->MoveNext();
                    }

                    $resArray = null;

                    if ( count( $result ) >= 1 ) {

                        $resArray = $result[0];

                        foreach ( $result as $row ) {
                            if ( $resArray['rating'] < $row['rating'] ) {
                                $resArray = $row;
                            }
                        }
                        $query = "UPDATE source_cdr SET sc_cc_key = " . $row['cc_id'] . " WHERE sc_id = " . $row['sc_id'];

                        $this->connect->_Execute( $query );
                        $this->connect->_Execute( "UPDATE comparable_cdr SET cc_is_compared = 1 WHERE cc_id = " . $resArray['cc_id'] );

                    }
                }
                $this->connect->CommitTrans();
                $sourceResult->MoveNext();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the answer you want, but to make it faster, you should try to answer this in SQL. In your top example, you would do something like

```
Select FIRST 1 duration, price, number
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.duration=b.duration and a.number = b.number
where b.price>=a.price
```

Now I am sure your table structure and comparison is more complicated, maybe you could share more of the data structure and rules on comparison and people here can help.

Another approach that would help but not be ideal, make sure you are ordering the data and if the minimum comparison happens, get out of your loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the "best" entry from comparableTable with only one query.

```
SELECT *
  FROM `comparable_table`
  ORDER BY ABS(CAST("3.00" AS DECIMAL) - `price`)
  LIMIT 1
```

The Value "3.00" is from one row in the source table.

This query is slow with large tables.

If you have a large table try this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
  (
    (
      SELECT *
        FROM `comparable_table`
        WHERE `price` >= CAST("3.00" AS DECIMAL)
        ORDER BY `price`
        LIMIT 1
    )  
    UNION DISTINCT
    (
      SELECT *
        FROM `comparable_table`
        WHERE `price` <= CAST("3.00" AS DECIMAL)
        ORDER BY `price` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
  ) AS `min_max`
  ORDER BY ABS(CAST("3.00" AS DECIMAL) - `price`)
  LIMIT 1
```

If you add an index on `price` this query use it and it should be faster on large tables.